# MySQL break up left table in LEFT JOIN query for performance enhancement

Tags: mysql, performance, join, split

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT pool.username
FROM pool
LEFT JOIN sent ON pool.username = sent.username
AND sent.campid = 'YA1LGfh9'
WHERE sent.username IS NULL
AND pool.gender = 'f'
AND (`location` = 'united states' OR `location` = 'us' OR `location` = 'usa');
```

The problem is that the pool table contains millions of rows and this query takes over 12 minutes to complete. I realize that in this query, the entire left table (pool) is being scanned. The pool table has an auto incremented id row.

I would like to split this query into multiple queries so that rather than scanning the entire pool table I scan 1000 rows at a time and in the next query I would pick up where I left off (1000-2000,2000-3000) and so on using the id column to keep track.

How can I specify this in my query? Please show examples if you know the answer. Thank you.

here are my indexes if it helps:

```
mysql> show index from main.pool;
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| pool  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     9275039 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| pool  |          1 | username |            1 | username    | A         |     9275039 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| pool  |          1 | source   |            1 | source      | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| pool  |          1 | location |            1 | location    | A         |       38168 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| pool  |          1 | pdex     |            1 | gender      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| pool  |          1 | pdex     |            2 | username    | A         |     9275039 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| pool  |          1 | pdex     |            3 | id          | A         |     9275039 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from main.sent;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| sent  |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | primary_key | A         |         351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sent  |          1 | username |            1 | username    | A         |         175 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sent  |          1 | sdex     |            1 | campid      | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sent  |          1 | sdex     |            2 | username    | A         |         351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

and here is the explain for my query:

```
----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pool  | ref   | location,pdex | pdex | 5       | const | 6084332 | Using where                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sent  | index | sdex          | sdex | 309     | NULL  |     351 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

here is the structure of the pool table:

```
| pool  | CREATE TABLE `pool` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`source` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `username` (`username`),
KEY `source` (`source`),
KEY `location` (`location`),
KEY `pdex` (`gender`,`username`,`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9327026 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

here is the structure of the sent table:

```
| sent  | CREATE TABLE `sent` (
`primary_key` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`from` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`campid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`),
KEY `username` (`username`),
KEY `sdex` (`campid`,`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=352 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

This produces a syntax error but this WHERE clause in the beginning is what im after:

```
SELECT pool.username
FROM pool
WHERE id < 1000
LEFT JOIN sent ON pool.username = sent.username
AND sent.campid = 'YA1LGfh9'
WHERE sent.username IS NULL
AND pool.gender = 'f'
AND (location = 'united states' OR location = 'us' OR location = 'usa');
```

Comment: How many rows does this query return? And is `location` a column of `pool`?

Comment: this query currently returns over 6 million rows. location is a column of pool.

Comment: Do you have any indexes? And what do you do with that 6 million rows?

Comment: i have added my index and explain information to my main post. Data in the rows are used to send messages to users.

Comment: Stupid question from me, but do you need all the data from the pool table?

Comment: yes, that's why I'm trying to scan the pool table in blocks and check those blocks against the sent table using the join. The message sending process needs the entire results of the query, but it doesn't necessarily need them all at once. The problem its causing is that it currently takes over 12 minutes for the message sending process to actually start sending anything and Im willing to bet this time is going to increase as the sent table grows (currently the send table is a few thousand rows but will grow to millions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting your query does not sound like the right approach.

The better way would be to fetch some records from your existing query, send your messages and then continue fetching.

---

Your query could benefit from another compound index on

```
pool( location, gender, username )
```

This should allow to run your complete query from `sdex` and your new index.

---

If you really want to split the query, an easy approach could be to

```
SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM pool
```

and then loop from min to max in steps of `1000`, and add `id >= r AND id < r+1000` to your query.

This could return `0` rows if you have gaps, but it would never return more than 1000 rows at once. A different compound index on `pool` including (`id`, `location`, `gender` and maybe `username`) could help for this query.

Comment: i will do that but even before I was using the location column the query time was the same. I would really like to split the pool table in the query so that I can use multiple queries.

Comment: i was going to loop in steps of 1000 using PHP. Is it possible to specify the start and end id in the query? I dont think just adding it to the end of the query accomplishes the goal. Where/how can I add that so that it only scans x-y id of the pool table in 1 query?

Comment: i want to do something like this but it produces an error: SELECT pool.username FROM pool WHERE id < 1000 LEFT JOIN sent ON pool.username = sent.username AND sent.campid = 'YA1LGfh9' WHERE sent.username IS NULL AND pool.gender = 'f' AND (location = 'united states' OR location = 'us' OR location = 'usa')

Comment: You need to add this condition to your existing `WHERE`-clause. `WHERE sent.username IS NULL AND id ...`

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem because the entire pool table will be searched before that clause.

Comment: Why do you think that this will happen? With the right index in place, the table should not have to be searched at all.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its using pool.location
Could try adding an index on gender, might no be a lot of help though.
Rationalising location to a country code in your data, and indexing that would probably be useful.

But the first index to add looks to be campid to me, that could make a serious dent in the number of records it has to test.

Comment: gender is part of the pdex index and campid is part of the sdex index